# Cordova/Phonegap iOS Camera Plugin Fork for OverlayView on iPad

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

On cordova/phongap 4.2 with iOS 8.1/8.2
with the plugin camera  http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera
on iOS iPad, 
I'm trying to add/modify the plugin in order to have a transparent image on top of the camrera preview ( UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )

I did :

1/ add a png image in the plugin forder :

```
cp path/to/viseur.png plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/src/ios/
```

2/ Add the line 
in the file plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/plugin.xml

```
<resource-file src="src/ios/viseur.png" target="viseur.png" />
// under <platform name="ios">
```

3/ added on plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/src/ios/CDVCamera.m

```
UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];
bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"viseur.png"];
cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = bgImage;
```

(I have a beat cheated because my file is on Ressources folder, I changed it to make it on top of the project)

anyway, this is not working well.
in fact ounce i got my CameraCapture View, it take likes 10seconds to see my overlay. when I change my code with something like

```
UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100)];
btnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
btnView.opaque = NO;
btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIButton *snapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100)];
snapButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[btnView addSubview:snapButton];
cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = btnView;
```

their is no problem.

any ideas .....